# Android Studio не показывает preview

Tags: android-studio

[image: я не знаю как исправить чтобы предварительный просмотр показывал и почему выделяет красным]

я не знаю как исправить чтобы предварительный просмотр показывал и почему выделяет красным

Comment: Наверное у вас библиотеки не подключены. Покажите скрипт сборки модуля.

Comment: уже решил обновил Gradle и все заработало